# Advice needed with disabling a JButton until required fields have been filled in - Java

Tags: java, jbutton, textfield

I am making a courier program in which the user can create a new account.
I want to have a next button that the user cannot press until the text fields have been filled in.

So a blank Name Field and Surname field would mean the next button cannot be pressed but if the fields have been filled in, the next button can be pressed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a KeyListener like this to your fields:

```
nameField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            super.keyReleased(e);
            if(nameField.getText().length() > 0 && surNameField.getText().length() > 0)
                nextButton.setEnabled(true);
            else
                nextButton.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });
```

This will check if the two fields are not empty, every time a key has been pressed in the field. If the condition is true, the next button will be enabled.

Comment: No problem. You'll also wan't to disable the button, if the user deletes the text again. Have updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: it doesn't work with nameField.getText().length() > 0 || surNameField.getText().length() > 0

Answer (score 1):

In simple term, try something like.

```
String text = textField.getText();
if (text.length()>0)
   button.setEnabled(true);
 ...
```

If you want to have the button enable on the fly then its a bit more complicated

EDIT :

complicated case:

```
Document textFieldDoc = myTextField.getDocument();
textFieldDoc.addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
 void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
   updated(e);
}
void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
   updated(e);
}
void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
   updated(e);
}
private void updated(DocumentEvent e) {
   boolean enable = e.getDocument().getLength() > 0;
   myButton.setEnabled(enable);
}
});
```

Comment: In that case you have to add a document listener which gets notified whenever a user modifies a text field and then in the update function for that you can setEnabled the button

Answer (score 0):

In your actionPerformed method, for every actionEvent checking, check whether the required fields are filled up, if so, set your button setEnabled(true). Perhaps a better answer can be provided if you can show us your code.